# Error "index out of range" but it isn't out of range PIL IMAGE CREATE

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm having some weird problem with my Python code. I'm passing a colored image to a black and white image.

I'm using PIL to work on images, this is my function:

```
class ImageEffects():

    def __init__(self, h, w, img):
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        self.img = img

    def grayScale(self):
        ret = [[(0, 0, 0) for x in range(self.h)] for y in range(self.w)]
        last = []
        try:
            for y in range(self.h):
                for x in range(self.w):
                    if self.inside(x, y):
                        pixel = self.img[x, y]
                        newColor = int((pixel[0] + pixel[1] + pixel[2])/3)
                        ret[y][x] = (newColor, newColor, newColor)
                        last = [x, y, self.inside(x, y), self.h, self.w]
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            print(last)
        return np.array(ret, dtype=np.uint8)

    def inside(self, x, y):
        return 0 <= x < self.w and 0 <= y < self.h
```

I used some try except to understand the problem. Now, I invoke this in this way:

```
im = Image.open(destination) # open the image to work
matrixImg = im.load()
h, w = im.size # size images            
newEffects = ImageEffects(h, w, matrixImg)
gray = newEffects.grayScale()
new_image = Image.fromarray(gray)
destination = "/".join([target, userId, "gray_" + fileHashed])
new_image.save(destination)
```

Try with this image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqo0B.jpg)
I got (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW2il.jpg)
and this is my exception log in console:

```
image index out of range # first print exception in grayscale function
[1114, 1114, True, 1280, 1115] # second print exception in grayscale function
```

But I'm not understanding why it goes in index out of range..

Maybe I'm so tired I can not see the error, but could you help me? Thank you so much guys!

## UPDATE: I GOT THE SOLUTION!

```
class ImageEffects():

def __init__(self, size, img):
    self.size = size
    self.img = img

def grayScale(self):
    ret = [[(0, 0, 0) for x in range(self.size[0])] for y in range(self.size[1])]
    last = []
    try:
        pixels = self.img.load()
        for x in range(self.size[0]):
            for y in range(self.size[1]):
                if self.inside(x, y):
                    pixel = pixels[x, y]
                    newColor = abs(int((pixel[0] + pixel[1] + pixel[2])/3))
                    ret[y][x] = (newColor, newColor, newColor)
                    last = [x, y, self.inside(x, y), self.size]
    except Exception as err:
        print(last)
        print(err)
    return np.array(ret, dtype=np.uint8)

def inside(self, x, y):
    return 0 <= x < self.size[0] and 0 <= y < self.size[1]
```

It works, I pass an "Image.open(file)" object to the img param of ImageEffects class. Then, I don't know where is the big difference between two codes.

Comment: I think you swapped `x` and `y` in `self.img[x,y]`

Comment: No, it isn't :-(!
I changed my self.img to Img object (now I initialize `ImageEffects(h, w, im)`).
I used the `self.img.getpixel((x, y))` but same error. (I tried also `self.img.getpixel((y, x))` And if I do `self.img.load()[y, x]` I got this image: https://i.imgur.com/lcsjCpi.png